# Ebean Query in Play framework column not found

Tags: playframework

I got the code

```
public static List <Post> getPostForTopic(String topicName) {
    List <Post> list = find.where().eq("topic_name",topicName).findList();
    return list;
}
```

SQL evoluation

```
# --- Created by Ebean DDL
# To stop Ebean DDL generation, remove this comment and start using Evolutions

# --- !Ups

create table post (
text                      varchar(255))
;

create table topic (
topic_name                varchar(255) not null,
constraint pk_topic primary key (topic_name))
;

create sequence topic_seq;




# --- !Downs

SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE;

drop table if exists post;

drop table if exists topic;

SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY TRUE;

drop sequence if exists topic_seq;
```

When I run it I have Execution exception:

```
[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Столбец "TOPIC_NAME" не найден Column "TOPIC_NAME" not found; SQL statement: select t0.text c0 from post t0 where topic_name = ? [42122-158] Bind values:[null] Query was: select t0.text c0 from post t0 where topic_name = ? ]
```

I and when I type query in my h2 database console like "Select * from topic", I got result that there is no table "TOPIC". Help me to find misstake please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you used a wrong finder.

I bet you create your `find` variable with something looking like this (I actually don't know what type you used as primary key):

```
 public static Finder<XXX,Post> find = new Finder<XXX,Post>(
    XXX.class, Post.class
  );
```

whereas you should use:

```
 public static Finder<String,Topic> find = new Finder<String,Topic>(
   String.class, Topic.class
 );
```